# create a custom field that let me include other posts

Tags: custom-field, ajax

I need to create a custom post type with a single custom field that is, basically, a list of other posts id.

In order to find that ids I would like to add a kind of "ajax search" ability to that custom field so that it will be able to find other post by simply start writing the first character of the title (let's say a behaviour not dissimilar to the one of the TAG field we normally have in wordpress backend).

Is it possible to obtain something like this?

Comment: What have you tried? WPSE coommunity does not appreciate "do it for me" questions.

Comment: Actually I've tried to search for an hint on google, but probably I can't find the right terms since the question is a little bit complex. I have very poor php skill honestly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to build this into a theme, it can be done quite easily with Advanced Custom Fields using the Relationship field type.

Comment: Well actually I do really need to insert into a theme